# как перейти из активити на фрагменты с сохранением drawer navigation

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть код, главной активити. При переходе на нужный пункт меню вместо фрагмента выбивает на главную страницу

```
public class ActivityTwo extends AppCompatActivity {

        FragmentPain fpain;
        FragmentDrug fdrug;
        FragmentTransaction ft;
        private Drawer.Result drawerResult = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



             fpain = new FragmentPain();
            fdrug = new FragmentDrug();
             ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


            drawerResult = new Drawer()
                    .withActivity(this)
                    .withToolbar(toolbar)
                    .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
                    .withHeader(R.layout.drawer_header)
                    .addDrawerItems(
                            new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_home).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home).withIdentifier(1),
                            new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_pain).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_heartbeat).withIdentifier(2),
                            new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_free_analog).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_medkit).withIdentifier(3),
                            new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_free_med_card).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_area_chart).withIdentifier(4),
                            new DividerDrawerItem(),
                            new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.off).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_power_off)

                    )
                    .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        // Обработка клика
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                            switch(drawerItem.getIdentifier()){
                                case 1:
                                ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fpain);
                                break;
                                case 3:
                                    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fdrug);
                                    break;
                            }
                            ft.commit();
                        }
                    })

                    .build();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Покажите логи ошибки. Наверное вы заново пытаетесь уже испоьзованную транзакцию использовать

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ошибок в логе нет

Comment: Попробуйте траннзакцию создавать прямо в методе onItemClick

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогает, к слову, если поможет, переход происходит так как будто открывается новое activity, а затем переход на главную